# CAST a date in Presto to next count

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, amazon-sagemaker

I would like to query Athena with JSON files. I matched creation_date with id because I would like to get a heatmap where on Y axis I have month, on X axis there day and I count the id's inside. I created a table with 2 columns:
creation_date date, id int. Next I am query with the below code:

```
SELECT CAST(creation_date as DATE) as ad_creation, 
       COUNT(id) as Total_ads 
FROM default.test 
GROUP BY CAST(creation_at_first as DATE)
```

unfortunately I am getting this error:

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql: SELECT CAST(creation_date as DATE) as ad_creation, COUNT(id) as Total_ads FROM default.testing_fresh_1 GROUP BY CAST(creation_date as DATE)

When I query `Select * from...`

I get results formatted like this:

```
creation_date   
2018-07-01 02:02:09 
2018-06-05 01:39:30 
2018-05-16 21:28:48 
2017-04-23 17:03:53
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From your `select *` result set, I guess there isn't `ID` column in your table.

You can try to use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(id)`

```
SELECT CAST(creation_date as DATE) as ad_creation, 
      COUNT(*) as Total_ads 
FROM default.test 
GROUP BY CAST(creation_date as DATE)
```

Comment: I would have one more question. Is there any chance to delete duplicates from the column id? It came out that there are some duplicate id values...

Comment: Which Id would you want to keep? min or max? I guess there is a way but depend on your logic.

Comment: I am extracting the 2 colums from a another table, much larger. It came out that there is a column named operation with the parameters insert, delete, update so the id which I am counting can be duplicated. Probably I need to delete the duplicate not in python but a step before, when I am querying the bigger table with sql.

Comment: @Michel I seem to like is another question.. you can create a new question thread and put you the question detail in the new question.

Comment: Basically I managed it, I had to add where with the specific operation type :).

Answer (score 1):

Try below Code.

```
SELECT CAST(creation_date as DATE) as ad_creation, 
        COUNT(id) as Total_ads 
FROM default.testing_fresh_1 
GROUP BY ad_creation
```